# При наследовании от виртуального класса, компилятор выдает ошибку

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь наследоваться от виртуального класса, компилятор выдает следующую ошибку:

> /home/anton/dev/techno_park/geo_index_service/test8/main.cpp:96: неопределённая ссылка на «ICashTable<int, int>::~ICashTable()»

Как это исправить?

```
#include <map>

template <class Key, class Val>
class ICashTable{
public:
    virtual ~ICashTable() = 0;
};

template <class Key, class Val>
class CashTableMap : ICashTable<Key, Val>{
private:
    std::map<Key, Val> map;
public:
    CashTableMap() = default;
    ~CashTableMap() = default;
};
```

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pure-virtual-destructor-c/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что происход при удалении обьекта класса `CashTableMap`?

1. Вызывается деструктор класса `CashTableMap`
2. Вызывается деструктор базового класса `ICashTable`

В базовом классе деструктор обьявлен как чисто вирутальная функция. Но тела у неё нет. Вот и получается ссылка на функцию без реализации. Запомните: если деструктор чисто виртуальный, то у него всё равно должно быть тело, которое программа сможет выполнить.
Кстати, это относится к любым чисто виртуальным функциям. Если функция чисто виртуальная, то это **не значит** что у неё не может быть тела. Может. И Вы можете вызывать её в функциях производного класса.